# Как сделать редирект после отправки формы yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Нужно ,чтобы после заполнения формы выполнялся редирект на другую страницу .Через action пробовал ,но данные в бд почему-то тогда не сохраняет.

views/form

```
<?php
use app\models\BriefForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/** @var $model BriefForm */
/** @var $this View */

$this->title = 'Brief';
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();  ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">

            <?= $form->field($model, 'site_name') ?>

            <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Что нужно сделать') ?></h3>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Создать новый') ?></h3>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'domain_name') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'register_new_domain', [
                            'template' => '{input}{label}',
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'checkbox-group'
                             ]
                        ])->checkbox(['class' => 'checkbox'], false)->label( 'Требуется зарегистрировать новый домен', ['class' => 'for-checkbox']); ?>
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'domen_exist', [
                            'template' => '{input}{label}',
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'checkbox-group'
                            ]
                        ])->checkbox(['class' => 'checkbox'], false)->label( 'Домен уже существует ', ['class' => 'for-checkbox']); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Обновить старый') ?></h3>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'domain_name') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'design', [
                            'template' => '{input}{label}',
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'checkbox-group'
                             ]
                        ])->checkbox(['class' => 'checkbox'], false)->label( 'Дизайн', ['class' => 'for-checkbox']); ?>
                       

            </div>

            
           
        </div>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

SiteController

```
public function actionForm()
{
    $model = new BriefForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

models/BriefForm

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class BriefForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function tableName(): string
    {
        return 'brief_form';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels(): array
    {
        return [
            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes): void
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'data acceepted');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, давно с php и с yii2 не работал, пишу по памяти. Нужно поправить ваш контроллер:

```
public function actionForm()
{
    $model = new BriefForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to('site/somelink'));
    }

    return $this->render('form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

У вас в коде: `return $this->refresh();` - Это перезагрузка страницы, если в кратце. Вам же нужно заменить это на `Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to('site/somelink'));` где site/somelink - это url, на который нужно совершать редиррект. Лучше указывать относительный, а не полный url, если переадресация идет в пределах вашего домена.

Comment: Если я помог, то буду рад если не только галку поставите, но и за вопрос проголосуете "за"))

Comment: Да , спасибо вы очень помогли , но проголосовать не могу ,не хватает репутации((

Comment: Ок, не страшно))